# Magento 2: Add product grid into ui form tab using insertListing

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent

I am adding a product grid into a form tab using `insertListing` of uiComponent

Tab code from uiCompnenet file

```
<fieldset name="products">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <insertListing>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="autoRender" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="ns" xsi:type="string">ui_component_file_name</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </insertListing>
</fieldset>
```

My `ui_component_file_name` file is using `custom_module_products_grid_data_source`, relevant code from di.xml is given below

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="custom_module_products_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

When I switch to the newly created tab I get the following error
[image: error]

This error should have appeared because `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory` is not extended from `Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult` and I need to declare `VirtualType` for grid collection something like below under my di.xml

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">mainTableName</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Question:
What is the main table for catalog products if I want to create grid collection via `VirtualType` or **How I add product grid into ui form tab using insertListing?**